# SQL Partition by with conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql, scope, partition-by

I want to partition the data on the basis of two columns Type and Env and fetch the top 5 records for each partition order by count desc. The problem that I'm facing is that I need to partition the Env on the basis of LIKE condition.
Data -

| Type | Environment | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | E1 | 1 |
| T1 | M1 | 2 |
| T1 | AB1 | 3 |
| T2 | E1 | 1 |
| T2 | M1 | 2 |
| T2 | CB1 | 3 |
| T2 | M1 | 5 |

The result that I want - Let's say I'm fetching top (1) record for now

| Type | Environment | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | M1 | 2 |
| T1 | AB1 | 3 |
| T2 | CB1 | 3 |
| T2 | M1 | 5 |

Here I'm dividing the env on condition (env LIKE "%M%" and env NOT LIKE "%M")

One approach that I can think of is using partition and union but this is a very expensive call due to the large amount of data that I'm filtering from. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Count DESC) AS maxCount
    FROM
      table 
    WHERE
      Env LIKE '%M%'
  ) AS t1
WHERE
  t1.maxCount <= 5
UNION
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Count DESC) AS maxCount
    FROM
      table 
    WHERE
      Env NOT LIKE '%M%'
  ) AS t1
WHERE
  t1.maxCount <= 5
```

Comment: One possible improvement is the LIKE/NOT LIKE in the where clause: If search string is simply 'M%' it improves performance.

Comment: @mseth . . . You should put your query in the question as *text*.  Then someone who wants to help can modify it when answering your question.  I also cannot tell what you want to accomplish.  Are you looking for 10 rows or 10 rows per type?

Comment: @gordon I'm looking for 10 rows per type for each environment where I want to differentiate the env into 2 categories - one is with env LIKE "M%" and the other is env NOT LIKE 'M%'.
So I should have 20 rows for each type ( 10 for "M%" and 10 for others).

Answer (score 3):

You would seem to want an additional `partition by` in your `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type, case when environment like '%M%' then 1 else 2 end)
                                order by count desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```